# Test class for below class

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, unit-test, class

```
   public class ExampleClass {
      public static void publishCaseUpdateNotifications(List<Case> cases) {
    List<Case_Updated__e> notifications = new List<Case_Updated__e>();
    for (Case c: cases) {
        notifications.add(new Case_Updated__e(
            Case__c = (String)c.Id,
            CreatedByName__c = UserInfo.getName(),
            CaseNumber__c = c.CaseNumber
        ));
    }


    List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(notifications);

    for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            for (Database.Error error : result.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('Error returned: ' +
                    error.getStatusCode() +' - '+
                    error.getMessage());
            }
        }
      }
     }
   }
```

My Test Class: getting error

```
 @isTest
  public class ExampleTestClass {

  @isTest
  static void testClassforExample(){

       Case testcase = new Case(Subject ='Test',);

    list<Case_Updated__e> caseUpdate = 
    ExampleClass.publishCaseUpdateNotifications(testcase );
      }  
   }
```

My Error is Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void publishCaseUpdateNotifications(Case) from the type ExampleTestClass

Please suggest me how to resolve this error.

```
   trigger Cases on Case (after insert) {
if(Trigger.isAfter) {
    System.debug('I will be replaced shortly!');
}
 }
```

Do we need test class for above trigger. Please suggest me too

Comment: your method takes a list of cases, you are passing a single case. These are not the same type of object.

Comment: In that case, do we need to pass list of cases over there.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Test Class had couple of issues.

1. your actual class`publishCaseUpdateNotifications` method expects list so you should pass `Lis<Case>` instead of `case`
2. your actual class method using saved list of cases not just instance of case.

3.your actual class method `publishCaseUpdateNotifications` returns nothing(void) but you added `list<Case_Updated__e> caseUpdate =` in your test class method. so you should take out.

suggestion: i strongly recommend to go through this [apex test class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm) for improve your programming skills.

Actual class:

```
  public class ExampleClass {
  public static void publishCaseUpdateNotifications(List<Case> cases) {
@testVisible private static List<Case_Updated__e> notifications = new List<Case_Updated__e>();
for (Case c: cases) {
    notifications.add(new Case_Updated__e(
        Case__c = (String)c.Id,
        CreatedByName__c = UserInfo.getName(),
        CaseNumber__c = c.CaseNumber
    ));
}


List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(notifications);

for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
        for (Database.Error error : result.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('Error returned: ' +
                error.getStatusCode() +' - '+
                error.getMessage());
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

}

```
    @isTest
       public class ExampleTestClass {
      @testSetup static void setup(){
           Case testcase = new Case(Subject ='Test');
           insert testcase;
    }

    @isTest
    static void testClassforExample(){

      List<Case> lsttestcases = [SELECT Id,CaseNumber FROM Case];
       Test.startTest();
       ExampleClass.publishCaseUpdateNotifications(lsttestcases );
       Test.stopTest();
     List<Case_Updated__c> casUp = [Select Id From Case_Updated__c];
    System.assertEquals(1, ExampleClass.notifications.size());
      }  
   }
```

Comment: Is it required to use two methods @testSetup static void setup() and  static void testClassforExample(){? possible to do in one method ?

Comment: you can both  insert the case and call the actual class  method `testClassforExample` in one method, but i gave best practice solution.

Comment: While using you are code, am getting error like this : Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context: void

Comment: Edited, Please check

Comment: Its working but need to use list<Case_Updated__e> caseUpdate.
 
If i use list<Case_Updated__e>with Error : Illegal assignment from void to List<Case_Updated__e>

Test.startTest();
        List<Case_Updated__e> casUp= ExampleClass.publishCaseUpdateNotifications(lsttestcases );
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(1, casUp.size());

Comment: Is it possible to use here this - System.assertEquals(1, casUp.size());

Comment: you should query before using `System.assertEquals(1, casUp.size())` like `List<Case_Updated__e> casUp = [Select Id From Case_Updated__e]; then use `System.assertEquals(1, casUp.size())` let me know if any issue occur

Comment: Its not working. Platform event will not support to query the record data. its just using for event purpose.

Comment: what errors you getting?

Comment: entity type Case_Updated__e does not support query

Comment: sorry, i wouldn't consider `Case_Updated__e` as PF event, i thought it's custom object, to cover the PF event, you should put PF event as`@testVisible` as i updated my solution, please check and do upvote if it's resolve your issue for helping others.

Comment: Thanks for you effort man. I got an answer without using the PF query.
How to cover the Database.Error error in test class?

Comment: can you please come up with new Questions. it's very hard to give a solution in a comment.